# Updating Game Database With PHP/Mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli

**Update**
Here's my form code

```
<form name = "form" method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" align = "center">
<tr><td><input type = "text" name = "command"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Enter"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "save" value = "Save"></td></tr>
</form>
```

So for this school project we have to make a text based game with PHP and Mysqli, and you have to have save function where it updates the players equipment and location in the database. For some reason, I can't get mine to work. I can echo the $_SESSION['location'] and it will display the users location fine.

When I click save I don't get a query error, but it doesn't update the location in the database either. For test purposes I tried to replace $updatelocation in the query with some random letters and it updated it in the database perfectly, but I can't figure out why it won't work when I have $updatelocation = $_SESSION['location']. My save code is below.

```
if(ISSET($_POST['save'])) {
$updatelocation = $_SESSION['location'];
$query = "UPDATE `isu`.`game_data` SET `location` = '$updatelocation' WHERE `game_data`.`user_id` =" . $_SESSION['id'];
mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or DIE ("Query problem");


}
```

Comment: Try escaping the value with `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['location'])`, maybe there are quotes in the value that break your query. Also you should look into defending against SQL injections and using prepared statements.

Comment: can you please share the form code with us and let us know the values of location. If it is a folder location you might have an issue with the directory separators.

Comment: @LeaTano Updated with form code, although I don't know what you mean by the value of location.

Comment: @matt1212 you need session_start(); at the top of your scrpit

Comment: I don't see session_start(); on the top of the code. if you don't have it please add <?php session_start();?> on the top og the file

Comment: @LeaTano I do have it. This is only a portion of my code.

Comment: i think i got it try $_SESSION['locations'] with s

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Then replace `or DIE ("Query problem");` with `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))`. You also need to make sure that `$_SESSION['id']` is an `int` and not a string. Use `var_dump($query);` to see what's passing through, or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nothing. Yes, $_SESSION['id'] is an int

Comment: What did var_dump reveal?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  string(2) "21" string(5) "shore"